# Vuetify Image load failed

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a problem Loading some Image in Vuejs using `v-img` inside `v-carousel-item`. I get this error.
Is there any error in my code?

```html
<template>
  <v-carousel cycle height="400" hide-delimiter-background show-arrows-on-hover>
    <v-carousel-item v-for="(image, i) in images" :key="i">
      <v-sheet height="100%">
        <v-row class="fill-height" align="center" justify="center">
          <!-- <div class="display-3">{{ slide }} Slide</div> -->
           <v-img :src="getImg(i)" />
          <!-- <v-img src="../MyAnimeArtworks/1.jpg"></v-img>  THIS LINE WORKS-->
        </v-row>
      </v-sheet>
    </v-carousel-item>
  </v-carousel>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      getImg(index) {
        return require(this.images[index]);
      },
      images: [
        "../MyAnimeArtworks/1.jpg",
        "../MyAnimeArtworks/2.jpg",
        "../MyAnimeArtworks/3.jpg",
        "../MyAnimeArtworks/4.jpg",
        "../MyAnimeArtworks/5.jpg"
      ],
      colors: [
        "indigo",
        "warning",
        "pink darken-2",
        "red lighten-1",
        "deep-purple accent-4"
      ],
      slides: ["First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth", "Fifth"]
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

[image]
[image]
I am sure about the location of my images

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vue.js - change undefined img source that I have created dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53978593/vue-js-change-undefined-img-source-that-i-have-created-dynamically)

Comment: hello, i have tried one of the solutions there and updated my code below, but its dosent seem to work :/

Comment: can you show  us the directory structure?

Comment: sure i can do that

Comment: try to replace the ../MyAnimeArt... with @/MyAnimeArt...

Comment: Nope, same problem ._.

Comment: did you emptied the cache?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211509/discussion-between-abdel-mounaim-and-hazel).

Comment: replace `"../MyAnimeArtworks/1.jpg"`  with `require("../MyAnimeArtworks/1.jpg")` and Vue will place them in the bundle and replace their names with the actual file names in the bundle. To avoid repetition, do `[...your files].map(i => require(i))`

Comment: @tao if you look at my getimg function, there is a require already

Comment: Seriously? You expect a function in `data`  to work? Try what I suggested, please. I'm not sure a method would work here, either. Afaik, require needs to happen at compile time, not at runtime. But it's possible your `getImg` might work as a method. Try it.

Comment: You can't have functions/methods in `data`. Data is for reactive properties. Vue reacts to their changes. Behind the scenes, they're observables. Rxjs-like.

Comment: @tao you were right sensei thanks :) can you explain to me what happened? because i have no idea whats going on ^^ ive seen some tutorials where ppl put functions inside their data or maybe i didn't pay enough attention but okay its great to know

Comment: When Vue compiles your component, it adds whatever you require (from relative paths or from `node_modules`) to the build and replaces the path in your code with a reference to the instance of that thing added to the build. That's the gist of it. So you need to map your paths with require so Vue does the adding to build and replacement. Because at runtime `../MyAnimeArt` doesn't actually exist (it would be relative to the page URL, not to node filepath). Inspect the component and you'll see they're replaced with some random links to files Vue created.

Comment: all right ithink i get it now, thanks lot !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vue uses [Vue Loader](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/asset-url.html) to handle assets. What it does is it parses your SFC's looking for any `require`d resources in your template or in your controller.

For any such relative URL found in template, Vue will wrap it inside a `require` call. Read about it [here](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/asset-url.html#transform-rules).

However, for any paths used in controller, you need to `require` them yourself (to tell the loader: add them to the bundle and replace the relative filepath URL with the relative application URL).

Long story short, simply do this

```
...,
data: () => ({
  ...
  images: [
    "../MyAnimeArtworks/1.jpg",
    "../MyAnimeArtworks/2.jpg",
    "../MyAnimeArtworks/3.jpg",
    "../MyAnimeArtworks/4.jpg",
    "../MyAnimeArtworks/5.jpg"
  ].map(i => require(i)),
  ...
}),
...
```

Do note that this translation from filepath relative urls to app relative urls happens at compile time, not at runtime.
To see what they get compiled into, simply `console.log(this.images)` in `mounted()`.